# Передача данных во view

Tags: php, mvc

Есть модель Articles, там есть 2 метода, первый getArticles, второй getComments

getComments принимает аргумент id article и отдаёт комментарии по id

Каким образом это передать во view? В шаблоне идёт перебор Записей, но как передать и комментарии? Не передавать же во view саму модель?

```
// controller
$this->render('articles', [
    'articles' => $modelArticles->getArticles(),
    'modelArticles' => $modelArticles
]);

// view
<?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
    <?php echo $modelArticles->getComments($article['id']); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: странно, у вас на странице одновременно выводятся и весь список новостей, и комментарии к каждой? Тогда либо загружайте сразу все комментарии так же массивом и просто доставайте нужные в цикле, либо аяксом подгружайте комментарии к статье при обращении к ней.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов, спасибо, попробую!